# Fortify scanning issue in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, fortify

I get an "Unsafe JNI (Input Validation and Representation, Semantic)" issue after I use Fortify to scan my code. I had referred to the recommendations from Fortify and searched some solution on website, but I can't fix the problem.

I follow the compliant solution recommended by Fortify in this [website](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/JNI00-J.+Define+wrappers+around+native+methods). 
I even use Fortify to scan the recommended code from the website, and get the same issue.

My code is shown below:

```
public final class JNI_Related {

// JNI
public native FileDescriptor open(String path, int baudrate, int data_bits, char parity, int stop_bits);

public native void close();

public FileDescriptor DoOpen(String mPath, int mBaudrate, int mData_bits, char mParity, int mStop_bits){

    if(mmPath.length() == 0){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    if((mmBaudrate < 0) || (mmData_bits < 0) || (mmStop_bits < 0) || (mmParity == 'a')){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    mFd = open(mmPath, mmBaudrate, mmData_bits, mmParity, mmStop_bits);

    if(mFd == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return mFd;
}

public void DoClose(){
    close();
}

static {
    System.loadLibrary("jniutill");
}
```

}

I really need some help!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

In your native methods, you have them declared as `public`:

```
public native FileDescriptor open(...);
public native void close();
```

The site you linked to in your question says that in order to resolve the Unsafe JNI issue, the `native` methods must be marked as `private`, making the only way you can reach the `native` method is through your `public` wrapper method that sanitizes the input parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the same Fortify issue after I changed public to private. @user1684458